# MVVM Light casting messages

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have the following Behavior:

```
    public class NavigateAndBroadcastAction : NavigateToPageAction
        {
            protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
            {            
                base.Invoke(parameter);
                Messenger.Default.Send<NavigatingMessage<ViewModelBase>>(new NavigatingMessage<ViewModelBase>(this, PassedObject), NavigationToken);
            }

            public ViewModelBase PassedObject
            {
                get { return (ViewModelBase)GetValue(PassedObjectProperty); }
                set { SetValue(PassedObjectProperty, value); }
            }

            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PassedObject.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PassedObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PassedObject", typeof(ViewModelBase), typeof(NavigateAndBroadcastAction), new PropertyMetadata(null)); 
...
    }
```

It basically uses the NavigateToPageAction (available in Blend also) but allows me to also broadcast a ViewModel object (I use it to navigate from List page to Detail page and to pass the selected object)

Xaml would look like this: (the PassedObject Binding is to an instance of DetailViewModel which inherits from ViewModelBase)

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
         <b:NavigateAndBroadcastAction TargetPage="/View/SubjectDetailPage.xaml" NavigationToken="SubjectDetailNavigationToken" PassedObject="{Binding}" />
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Now, I want to register for the Message:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NavigatingMessage<DetailViewModel>>(this, NavigationToken, true, Action);
```

But that doesnt work. What does work, is to register for `NavigatingMessage<ViewModelBase>` and then cast the received message to `NavigatingMessage<DetailViewModel>`. Is there a way around that?

Can it be done so that the messenger detects the actual type of object being sent and correctly delivers to objects that registed for that type?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Are you getting a compilation error? An exception?

Comment: No, the message simple does not get delivered

Comment: Can't you send the message of the correct type?

Comment: Well, how would I do that? I want the behavior to be generic, so that in Xaml I can bind to ANY object that inherits from ViewModelBase..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be to use reflection to send the message, by creating the message with the correct generic type at runtime.
Another one would be to use `dynamic` and type inference:

```
protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
{            
    base.Invoke(parameter);
    dynamic viewModel = PassedObject;
    Messenger.Default.Send(GetMessage(this, viewModel), NavigationToken);
}

private NavigatingMessage<T> GetMessage<T>(NavigateToPageAction action, T item)
{
    return new NavigatingMessage<T>(action, item);
}
```

---

The version using reflection is a bit more messy:

```
protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
{            
    base.Invoke(parameter);
    Send(PassedObject, NavigationToken);
}

void Send(ViewModelBase objectToSend, string navigationToken)
{
    var genericMessageType = typeof(NavigatingMessage<>)
    var viewModelType = objectToSend.GetType();
    var messageType = genericMessageType.MakeGenericType(viewModelType);
    var message = Activator.CreateInstance(messageType, this, objectToSend);

    var method = typeof(Messenger).GetMethods()
                                  .Single(x => x.Name == "Send" &&
                                               x.GetParameters().Count() == 2 &&
                                               x.GetParameters()
                                                .First()
                                                .ParameterType
                                                .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                                                 == genericMessageType);
    method.MakeGenericMethod(viewModelType)
          .Invoke(Messenger.Default, new [] { message, navigationToken });
}
```

This code assumes that `NavigationToken` is a `string`. If not, just change the type of the second parameter of the `Send` method. If `Messenger` only contains one overload of the `Send` method you could simplify the condition in `Single`. On the other hand, if there are a lot of overloads of that method, you might need to refine it.

Comment: Could you give an example of the reflection approach? I am targeting WP7 which, as it turns out, doesn't support the dynamic keyword

Comment: a-may-zing :) I had to modify it a bit (removed the onther condition after Count() == 2 since it threw exceptions and instead of "method.MakeGenericMethod(viewModelType)" I used "method.MakeGenericMethod(messageType)" and it works like a charm :) I had no idea reflection had such possibilities :)

Comment: @TomášBezouška: I only tested it with stub methods that were named the same as the real ones in your code. It is very much possible that I used some wrong types for those methods, so your changes should be alright. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you send the message as `Messenger.Default.Send<NavigatingMessage<DetailViewModel>>(new NavigatingMessage<DetailViewModel>(this, PassedObject)` you would be able to receive the message as you wish, without casting.

Comment: Yes, but that would defeat the purpose of the behavior - I want to be able to send any object, that inherits from the ViewModelBase

Comment: mmm then i'm afraid you would have to live with casting :(

Comment: @LOSTCODER: That's not correct. Please see my answer, you might learn something new :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yeah I saw it and up voted! :) Really clean bro. I knew reflection would cut it but using dynamic was way too sleek! Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the current version of MVVM Light. I am thinking of improving that in the future but it is quite tricky...

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Would this help in any way in implementing this feature? The DLR is quite powerful.